# How To Do See If The Field Values Are Unique In A Table

Tags: php, yii

I have a model class file called `test.php`. I have two fields - `Function type` and `Service Type`. So, now I want to see that both `Function type` and `Service Type` are unique. i.e `Function type` and `Service Type` cannot be the same in more than one row.

I'm using the create and update function for this. I want both the functions to see if `Function type` and `Service Type` are repeated, then don't save it and if not repeated then save it.

I'm using the below example to illustrate the rows -

```
   ID            Function type      Service Type
    1                    2                3
    2                    4                5
    3                    7                8
```

This has to be done in Yii framework and not at MySQL level. How can I do this validation before saving. Please guide me on this.

Comment: Before saving, check if it exists. If so, don't do anything. If not, save. What are you missing?

Comment: @HamzaKubba No can I do it model class. I think you are asking me to do it in controller.Am I right..

Comment: Either works... I'm mostly asking you what the problem is...

Comment: @HamzaKubba See I'm asking whether I should right a query condition to get the list of all function type and service type and check if it is null and then update it into database. My problem is I want to know the procedure to check if that data is unique or not

Comment: There are many ways to do that. It doesn't matter that much which as long as you feel your code and structure is clean... I don't know what your structure is like so I can't advise on the ideal location for the code. Anyway, let's say you want to add a record with FT = 5 and ST = 7. Then you check the database for any existing records with FT = 5 and/or ST = 7 (either and or or, depending on what you want). If there are existing records, you don't add the new record, otherwise you do. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
function rules(){
      ... // Other rules
      array('service_type','validate_unique_types'),

}

public function validate_unique_types($attribute, $params){

        if(!empty($this->function_type) && !empty($this->service_type)){
            $count = YourModel::model()->count('function_type = :function_type AND service_type = :service_type',array(':function_type'=>$this->function_type, ':service_type'=>$this->service_type));
            if($count){
                $this->addError($attribute, "repeated!!");
            }
        }

}
```

If the user input a 'service_tipe' and 'function_type', the 'validate_unique_types' function controls if exist any reg on the DB with both values.

Comment: I get this error : Object of class Groupzservicelookup could not be converted to string